# What are the benefits of a cumulative component sum hashcode function over a regular summation of the ASCII values?

Tags: algorithm, hashtable

In the case of regular hash tables encoding text. Is it that you just get less collisions because the range of numbers is larger?

Edit:
Cumulative component sum is the function which returns the factorial of the string ASCII values. ie s="string" -> s[0] + (s[0]+s[1])+ (s[0]+s[1]+s[2]) ... till len(s).

Regular sum is just s[0]+s[1]+s[2]...

Comment: Define 'cumulative component sum hashcode function', and, while you're at it, 'regular summation of the ASCII values'. Values of what?

Comment: Cumulative component sum is the the factorial of the string ASCII values. ie s="string" -> s[0] + (s[0]+s[1])+ (s[0]+s[1]+s[2]) ... till len(s). Regular sum is just s[0]+s[1]+s[2]...

Comment: That's not a factorial. In any case I see no advantage from a hashing point of view. It just weights the first element more than the second, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often a several English words use exactly the same letters, but in a different order. (Those words are [anagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/anagram) of each other).
(For example, angel / angle / glean ).

Because order doesn't matter in simple addition, all of the anagrams of a word have the same sum.
So using simple sums as your hash function always leads to a collision when two different keys are anagrams of each other.

I've never heard the term "Cumulative component sum hashcode", but from your description it is the same as the second part of [Fletcher's checksum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fletcher%27s_checksum).

Using a hash function that gives *different* results for the same letters in a different order, such as the second part of Fletcher's checksum (or the entire Fletcher's checksum), leads to fewer collisions in a hash table.

Answer (score 0):

Basically int(t) + int(h) + int(e) for the hashcode is the same is eth or het.
This is why cumulative component sum hashcode is better is more individual so that
the != eht when the hashcode function is used. This reduces the number of collisions.